# What is the equivalent of 'variable'.text in cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos, text, nsstring

In an iPhone application I can write something like this with no error (And have 'someThing' a label.:

```
NSString *thing = someThing.text;
```

But I am trying to do this in cocoa. I need to set the text on the label 'someThing' as 'thing'. It doesn't work in Cocoa, but does in iOS. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Look up the class in the mac documentation, there is a corresponding appkit class for almost all the UIkit stuff so like UITextfield is NSTextfield, with that info you should be able to find it. My guess is that the thing you want to do is [someThing setStringValue:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa classes don't use as many properties (`.foo`), rather, they use getters (`[object foo]`) and setters (`[object setFoo:value]`). In reality properties are just a wrapper over `value` and `setValue:` methods.

To set the text of a `NSTextField` (label), you would use `[myLabel setStringValue:@"Hello World!"]`.

To get its value you would use `NSString *string = [myLabel stringValue]`.

Most subclasses of `NSControl` implement `stringValue`, `intValue`, etc.